# How to delete pointers from memory and restore them later in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I've created an array of objects in C++, using QT Creator, which set up the grid of a simple puzzle game. When a game session is finished, and I want to start a new game, I delete the memory usage of the array with the operator delete, so I prevent any memory leak. But, since my array is global and I'd have troubles to redaclare it dynamically on every new game session, would this cause the array to be no longer usable? Would I need to redaclare it?

Comment: Without seeing your dynamic allocation, global array, etc it is hard to know what you are talking about. Can you show a minimal example of what you are talking about and clarify your question?

Comment: Exactly how do you declare the array? If you declare it on the heap (with `new`), then yes, you must redeclare it; if you declare it on the stack (without `new`) then calling `delete` on it will cause you problems more serious than a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, it's an array of pointers: QPushButton *box[256]

Comment: `QPushButton *box[256]` - then you may want to loop and `delete` the individual pointers, then later recreate them with another loop and `box[I] = new QPushButton(...);`, thereby restoring the default or some newly determined attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your "global" is a pointer to the array you've initialised à la...

```
Data* p;
```

Which you later initialise:

```
p = new Data[n];
p[0] = get_first_value();
...
```

After a game you can delete it:

```
delete[] p;
```

When you're ready to start a new game, you can use it again - the same declaration - by assigning it to address newly allocated memory:

```
p = new Data[n];
p[0] = get_first_value();
...
```

The `n` values need not be the same for each game, if for whatever reason you decide you need more or less data.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The entire point of using `delete` is to tell the computer, "Hey, I was previously using this memory, but I won't need it anymore. Ever. Do whatever you want with it."

Then the computer can recycle that memory for whatever purpose it sees fit.

In other words, if you *do* need to use the memory again, *don't* `delete` it!